# Encoding in python for *only* alphanumerics

Tags: python, encoding, escaping

Is there a codec in python that will escape everything that is not in the ascii range of 48-57 or 65-122 (i.e. not a alpha-numeric)

The only exception would be a slash and backslash characters.

Ideally, I would want to convert something like this:

```
/MyString/My#^/Blah/
```

To this:

```
/MyString/My\x23\x5e/Blah/
```

I know that there is the string-escape encoding which does something similar, but I need a custom range of characters to be encoded. I'm looking for clever suggestions or modules  that can do this efficiently.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` with a function parameter like this:

```
s = "/MyString/My#^/Blah/"
import re
print re.sub(r'[^\w/\\]', lambda m: '\\x%x' % ord(m.group(0)), s)
#/MyString/My\x23\x5e/Blah/
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked into this, but the first thing that came to mind is the string class translate function.

http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.translate

If you put together your encoding string correctly (i.e. write a script to do so) the translation should do the job. 
Hope that helps.

Comment: First thing that came to my mind too, but then thinking about it, it would be a huge pain to write the translation table for "all characters except for..."